# replacing values in pig latin

Tags: apache-pig

I have a dataset in form:

```
id1, id2, id3
```

Either of id1,id2 or id3 (or all three.. or any two) can be missing in a record.

Now if id1 is missing I want to replace it with 1

```
 id2 by 3 
 id3 by 7
```

How do I do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the bincond operator to test if the value is null and then replace it with the desired value.  From Programming Pig, [Chapter 5](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/intro_pig_latin.html):

```
2 == 2 ? 1 : 4 --returns 1 
2 == 3 ? 1 : 4 --returns 4 
null == 2 ? 1 : 4 -- returns null
2 == 2 ? 1 : 'fred' -- type error, both values must be of the same type
```

In your example,

```
id2 IS NULL ? 3 : id2
```

Comment: Hi. I tried the solution but I am getting an error saying that mismatched input "IS' expecting semi colon?

Comment: I think I've had similar messages before -- try adding extra parentheses. This is how I always write my binconds: `((id2 IS NULL) ? 3 : id2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Should there be some "foreach " loop??? Can you please comment here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400940/bincod-evaluation-in-pig