# bincod evaluation in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to replace the missing values with some precomputed value.

So i posted the question here and followed the advice and here is the code snippet

```
input = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS
(
id1:double  ,  id21:double  );

gin = foreach input generate
        id1 IS NULL ? 2 : id1,
        id2 IS NULL ? 4 : id2;
```

But I am getting an error mismatched input 'IS' expecting SEMI_COLON?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replacing values in pig latin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386609/replacing-values-in-pig-latin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding parentheses in the bincond.  The following works properly for me:

Contents of `input`:

```
0.9,1.11
,0.3
10.3,
```

Script:

```
inp = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id1:double, id2:double );

gin = foreach inp generate
    ((id1 IS NULL) ? 2 : id1),
    ((id2 IS NULL) ? 4 : id2);

DUMP gin;
```

Output:

```
(0.9,1.11)
(2.0,0.3)
(10.3,4.0)
```